# How we can ignore html lines for validation in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, mustache

how we can ignore html lines in vscode? for example:

```
...
<style>
  body{
    font-size:{{fontSize}}px;
  }
</style>
...
```

I have use mustache for variables, and {{fontSize}} is show as warning

I would like to be able to post comments like

```
  ...
  <!-- lint: disable -->
  <style>
    body{
      font-size:{{fontSize}}px;
    }
  </style>
  <!-- lint: enable-->
  ...
```

or

```
  ...
  <style>
    // lint: disable
    body{
      font-size:{{fontSize}}px;
    }
    // lint: enable
  </style>
  ...
```

Comment: Do you want to disable HTML/CSS linting entirely or just get support for Mustache? Have you tried to Mustache extension to figure out if it suits your needs?

Comment: I want disable linting for a section of code

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned what plugin is actually giving you the validation error, but if it's [HTML-validate](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=html-validate.vscode-html-validate), then you can use comments such as this, to disable validation for the next occurrence:

```
<!-- [html-validate-disable-next attribute-allowed-values] -->
```

Or this variant, which applies for the remainder of the current HTML block:

```
<!-- [html-validate-disable-block attribute-allowed-values] -->
```

The full syntax is available in their docs under [inline-configuration](https://html-validate.org/usage/#inline-configuration)